# Issue while Invoking a Lambda function from another Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Parent Lambda function from which I am invoking a child Lambda function. I want to invoke the child function asynchronously so I am using Invocation type as 'Event'. I am using API gateway to call the Parent Lambda function. When I try to send a single or 2-3 requests to the API endpoint, I see the logs in the Parent Lambda function only and not in the child lambda function(i.e. it is not able to invoke the child function). It is not able to invoke child function when I hit fewer requests. However if I hit 10-15 requests at a time then it starts reflecting the logs in both parent and child Lambda function. Whereas the ideal behavior should be even if I invoke it once it should reflect in both the function logs.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

const function1 = {
        FunctionName: 'child_lambda',
        InvocationType: 'Event',
        Payload: JSON.stringify(event)
        };
    lambda.invoke(function1).promise();
}
```

Here I have mentioned the code snippet I am using to invoke the child Lambda function.

Comment: Are you *await*ing the lambda invocation promise?

Comment: No, I don't want to wait for the response from the child Lambda function

Comment: You can't just get the promise and then not do anything with it. Your lambda probably exits before anything happens. You need to await it.

Comment: Ok, What if I remove the promise and just simply invoke it.

Comment: I don't think that will work either. I don't know the lambda sdk but I suspect if you've set the type to Event, as you've done, then awaiting the promise will simply wait for the the lambda to be kicked off, rather than waiting for it to return. You'd have to test it to be sure but I suspect that's it, otherwise what's the point of calling Event "asynchronous" because the non-Event invocation types would also have to be awaited in the code. So I think awaiting the Event invocation will be what you want.

Comment: As @404 mentioned, you have to write `await lambda.invoke(function1).promise();`. You will not wait for Lambda to return as you used `Event` as `InvocationType`. If you don't want to use await, you should remove `async` from function definition and start to use callback, but I don't like this approach. Question: Why do you need to call a Lambda from another Lambda?

Comment: @404 is correct.  Awaiting the promise of an `Event` invocation waits only for the lambda service to acknowledge that it will invoke your function.  This is required if your handler is also async.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding this in the end ?

`return await lambda.invoke(function1).promise();`